# richfaces a4j:htmlCommandLink keep alive request scoped bean

Tags: richfaces, request, ajax4jsf, jsf-1.2, managed-bean

I have a request scoped bean and I am using Richfaces `@KeepAlive(ajaxOnly=true)` to keep the bean alive between ajax requests. On my page I have some `a4j:commandButton`, and the backing bean is ok, is kept alive between button clicks.

The problem is I need to use an `a4j:htmlCommandLink`. When I click the link it creates me another bean in the backend, but I need the same bean, not a new one.

Here I have some extacts from my code:

```
@KeepAlive(ajaxOnly=true)
public class testBean
{
   public void testMethod(ActionEvent ae) {
   ...
   }
   ...
}

<a4j:htmlCommandLink value="Print" target="_blank" 
     actionListener="#{testBean.testMethod}" />
```

How can I keep the bean alive when I use (click) a `htmlCommandLink`?

Comment: Is it with JSF2.0 or JSF1.2 you are trying this implementation? Your question is tagged with jsf-1.2 but I don't think it supports KeepAlive annotation? Should it be tagged jsf-2.0?

Comment: Its my bad. I have never used this tag for JSF1.2.Sorry for my ignorance.It can be used in JSF1.2 as in http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/07/view-scope-in-richfaces/

Comment: Can a workaround like <a4j:htmlCommandLink value="Print"><a4j:support event="onclick" disableDefault="true" action="testBean.testMethod" oncomplete="window.open(url)" /> </a4j:htmlCommandLink> help ?

Answer (score 0):

From the `a4j:htmlCommandLink`:

> `<a4j:htmlCommandLink>` works as standard `<h:commandLink>`

Remember that this component doesn't use an ajax call, so the behavior will be as a common request/response to the server. In your bean, change the behavior of the KeepAlive annotation to `ajaxOnly=false` to avoid these problems.

Comment: Can a workaround like `<a4j:htmlCommandLink value="Print"><a4j:support event="onclick" disableDefault="true" action="testBean.testMethod" oncomplete="window.open(url)" /> </a4j:htmlCommandLink>` help ?

Comment: I haven't tried in that way. Still, `<a4j:htmlCommandLink />` is used to open results in new window, and I have only used for file download because this behavior can't be done via ajax call (like in `<a4j:commandButton />` or `<a4j:commandLink />`), for all other cases, when I need a link, I use `<a4j:commandLink />`.